# SQL in Excel returns different results than SQL in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ssms

Ok this is driving me crazy.

I have a stored procedure that populates a table which I then have a view which I connect to from Excel to display the results.

The data results are by month i.e. JAN FEB MAR, etc.

First, the results when run from SSMS are correct, the results from Excel are NOT correct but not all the numbers are incorrect, just four results out of 13 (AUG, OCT, DEC & TOT).

From SSMS if I run the following procedure, the table bfPNRbyMonth_Customer_Results is populated correctly and if I select from the view that the Excel spreadsheet is linked to, the data is correct.

```
sp_bfPopulatePNRbyMonth_Customer N'A', N'Forecast', 2019
```

If I run the same procedure from VBA within the spreadsheet I get different results for four of the columns.

```
Dim objCn As ADODB.Connection
Dim vFiscalYearA As Variant
Dim sDataTypeA As String

vFiscalYearA = Trim(Sheet2.Cells(9, 2).Value)
sDataTypeA = Sheet2.DataTypeA.Value

Set objCn = New ADODB.Connection

objCn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=******;UID=readonly;PWD=readonly;DATABASE=******"
objCn.Open

sSQL = "sp_bfPopulatePNRbyMonth_Customer N'A', N'" & sDataTypeA & "', " & vFiscalYearA
objCn.Execute sSQL
```

Criteria is sDataTypeA = "Forecast" and vFiscalYearA = 2019

Anyone ever run into this?

Thanks!

Edit: I changed the VBA to use parameters and within the procedure wrote the parameters to a table to make sure they're passing correctly and they are:

```
 id dataset datatype    fiscalyear
 1  A       Forecast    2019
 2  B       Budget      2019
```

Comment: Are you positive that sSQL is the exact query? Like, have you set a break point and looked and confirmed it? Second, I've seen Excel do some funky stuff with dates and integers. Make sure you're not getting some goofy serial date conversion somewhere.

Comment: Positive, confirmed in the immediate window.  What's especially strange is that the other nine columns are correct.  It's just the four noted that are wrong.

Comment: Are you able to add any logging code to the stored procedure - such as writing the parameters into a separate table? I bet you'll find out the the parameters passed from Excel don't match what you expect.

Comment: Also, parameters, parameters, parameters... you should be using parameters to pass in the arguments to the sproc, not string concatenation.

Comment: When you are testing in SSMS, are you testing with the `readonly` account? Maybe it's a schema issue. I assume you made sure the server is correct.

Comment: Running the SP in SSMS with the sa account.  I changed the connection in Excel to the sa account to test and vice versa, same results.  I know I should change to parameters, will do so once I solve this =)

Comment: Obligatory link...http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Ok ok, so I altered the code to use parameters and got the same result.

Comment: But are the parameters actually as exected, or are they getting munged like @JacobH suggested above?

Comment: I would assume they're as expected since 9 of the 13 columns are correct and match the SSMS results.  Also of note within VBA I run this block of code for two different result sets, the second matches the SSMS results perfectly.  Will check the parameters now.

Comment: Updated OP, parameters are being passed correctly

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with the Provider you are using to connect and how it is handling datetimes. I've encountered a very similar issue before with Oracle SQL where MSDAORA seems to be more intuitive with certain conversions while OraOLEDB.Oracle is more explicit. Can you share the relevant stored procedure SQL that is handling the input parameters as well as bucketing by date?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend checking the plan in the cache, and verify the parameters are correct.

Comment: I'm not using any datetimes, the year is being passed in as an integer and the stored procedure handles everything else.  And it's being passed in correctly.  So bizarre.